# Why do I get the error 'Can't find Unicode property definition "\"' with this regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Pascal 14241 Mar 28
```

I want to check that it matches this format:

```
Name size date
```

When I run my code I get an error:

```
Can't find Unicode property definition "\" at testar.pl line 13, <IN> line 2 (#1
)
(F) You may have tried to use \p which means a Unicode
property (for example \p{Lu} matches all uppercase
letters). If you did mean to use a Unicode property, see
"Properties accessible through \p{} and \P{}" in perluniprops
for a complete list of available properties. If you didn't
mean to use a Unicode property, escape the \p, either by \\p
(just the \p) or by \Q\p (the rest of the string, or
until \E).

Uncaught exception from user code:
    Can't find Unicode property definition "\" at testar.pl line 13, <IN> line 2.
at testar.pl line 13
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/usr/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use diagnostics;

open (IN, "sample1.txt") or die "cant read words from file: $!";

while (<IN>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~/\p\w+\s+\d+\s\w+\s+\d+/){
        print "$_ \n";
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try executing formatted code. Maybe that will work.

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\p` must be followed by a single-character Unicode property (e.g. `\pL` – letter) or by a property in curlies (e.g. `\p{Lu}` – uppercase letter).

`\p\` is not a valid since `\` is not a valid Unicode property. Indeed, you don't need `\p` at all in your regex.

```
/\w+\s+\d+\s\w+\s+\d+/
```

If you intended to anchor at the start of the line, use `^`.

```
/^\w+\s+\d+\s\w+\s+\d+/
```

Your statement only match the input string against the regex. It doesn't capture any value (and you didn't tell perl what is interesting to capture).

In order to capture the words you should use:

```
/^(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s(\w+\s+\d+)/
```

The the captures values will be available as `$1` for the 1st capture, `$2` for the second, and so on. You can then just print what you need:

```
print $1." ".$2." ".$3."\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

but when i run it dont print out just the name size and date, it prints out the whole text file